# In jqplot, how to show x-axis on top, and how to hide axis label

Tags: jqplot

I have a jqplot object that has x-axis tick marks/labels rendered on bottom. Basically, there is a stack of charts, all using the same x-axis. I would like to reclaim the bottom axis area from the middle charts for the plot lines.

- How can I dynamically relocate the x-axis to top (i.e., northward)
- How to make the x-axis label go away? For this I tried

  ```
  plotobject.axes.xaxis.showLabel = false; 
  plotobject.replot();
  ```

but that seems to have no visible effect. `plotobject` is what's returned by the original `$.jqplot()` call and I am using `$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer` for xaxis.renderer. I have access only to the plot object.

Thanks

Comment: Woe! when I hide the xaxis, point tracking via highlighter quietly quits.

Answer (score 3):

This simple CSS solution is working for me to put the x-axis labels on top of the chart.

```
.jqplot-xaxis {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: awesome stuff... made a complex task simple as anything.. thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

well, the label for each axis (which is the axis title) has it's own renderer, and thus it's own options. I use the plugin one ( http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-canvasAxisLabelRenderer-js.html ) but also the default has a show: true/false setting. ( http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisLabelRenderer-js.html )

it should look something like this:

```
axes: {
    xaxis: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        label: 'Dates',
        labelOptions: {
            show: true,
            fontSize: '10pt'
        },
    }
}
```

For putting the x-axis on top, I'm not sure what your problem realy is, but I try to select it with jquery and set it's z-index to something high to bring it on top. Take a look at http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotCssStyling-txt.html for some selection ideas.

Comment: So, hiding labels now works. Thanks... For bringing the x-axis on top -- my bad, I had really meant to ask how bring it to North of the plot

Comment: for that you can use the x2axis. The settings work just the same, the trick is to 'connect' your series to that axis. On the examples page are a few examples that have this. ( http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html )

Comment: OK, so I can dupl the attributes of xaxis into x2axis and discard the xaxis... Sounds good, thanks.